# Detecting negative weight cycle Bellman ford algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have read this algorithm  Bellman ford shortest paths which detects a negative weight cycle . [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)

The algorithm runs for number of (vertices-1) times to avoid infinite looping and it successfully detects the negative weight cycle . That's great but, my doubt is what is the need to detect the negative weight cycle ? when the algorithm runs for fixed number of times and terminates by itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Shortest path does not make sense if there is a negative cycle. You can always find shorter path by passing it. Bellman Ford finds you the shortest path if there exists one (no negative cycle) or tells that there is no shortest path.

Basically, after x iterations we get for each vertex u shortest path from v to u using no more than x edges. If there is no negative cycle the answer will never use more than V - 1 edges, so the algorithm won't find any better path after V - 1 iterations. However, if there exists a negative cycle then we may always decrease the lenght of any path by passing through it, so the algorithm won't stop.

Comment: "Shortest path does not make sense  if there is a negative cycle" ? Support you answer with a valid example .

Comment: @RajGopalbh4 support your counter-argument with a valid example.

Comment: @RajGopalbh4, I really though that was obvious, but sure, here you go. Consider graph with two vertices, A and B, and two edges, (A, B) and (B, A). Let c((A, B)) = 2 and c((B, A)) = -5. What's the shortest path from A to B? 2? No, A -> B -> A -> B gives -1, then this must be the answer. But A -> B -> A -> B -> A -> B gives less. And so on. There is no such a thing as the shortest path, since there always exists a smaller one. Whatever the graph is, if you have a negative cycle you can always find shorter path by passing through the cycle more times.

Answer (score 1):

The Bellman-Ford find the shortest paths from a given vertex to all other vertices in the graph.

If there is a negative cycle, there will be at least one vertex whose distance corresponds to the path where this negative cycle has been walked at least one. 
If you increase the first iteration to run not |V|-1, but 2*(|V|-1), the distance to this vertex will be reduced! If you increase to 3*(|V|-1) the distance will be reduced again! You can increase indefinitely the iteration, and the distance to this vertex will be reduced indefinitely.

In other words, **the algorithm doesn't converge to the shortest paths**.

This is why you need to detect the negative cycle using

```
    for each edge (u, v) with weight w in edges:
           if distance[u] + w < distance[v]:
               error "Graph contains a negative-weight cycle"
```

In the wikipedia case it is considered an error, but the algorithm can be used to purposefully detect negative cycles.

Comment: since you asked me to give a valid example . Let me explain you by keeping what in mind the algorithm was developed ? Consider this graph (A,B)=2 (B,C)=3 (C,A)=-8 . Let A be the root of this directed graph . Since A is the root distance[A]=0 , After running the bellman ford algorithm , the distance[A]=-6 . This contradicts our assumption , since we assumed that distance[A]=0 and its value will never reduce or increase . So keeping this in mind the algorithm was developed so that root never involves in -ve weight weight cycle. Remaining vertices distance value can be anything

Comment: In which line of algorithm are we checking this condition ?  "the algorithm doesn't converge to the shortest paths."

Comment: I like your example. But can you be clear about the point you try to make? If you end up with `distance[A]=-6, which contradicts our assumption`, then you just found a negative cycle. You should stop and return an error.

Comment: It is this case `-1= -3 + 2 = distance[A] + w_ab < distance[B] = 2`.